# Should I use /* */ or /** */ for the copyright in the top of a java file?

Tags: java, coding-style, comments, javadoc, copyright-display

There is a copyright comment in each java file, but I don't know which one should I use: `/* */` or `/** */`?

```
 /*
  * Copyright ...
  */
 import java.util.*
 ...
```

or

```
/**
 * Copyright ...
 */
import java.util.*
....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This rather old (circa 1999) Sun [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#3441) document suggests `/* */`.

More specifically, it suggests the following layout for your class/interface file(s):

- Beginning comments

  ```
  /*
   * Classname
   * Version information
   * Date
   * Copyright notice
   */
  ```
- `package` and `import` statements
- Class and interface declarations (which includes Javadoc comments for the class - see table entry #1).

Example:

```
/*
 * MyClass
 *
 * v1.0
 *
 * 2011-11-29
 * 
 * This file is copyrighted in an awesome way.
 */
package com.example.mypackage;

import com.example.otherpackage;

/**
 * Javadoc comments for the class.
 */
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Javadoc will only gather `/** ... */` comments if they are directly before any declaration to be documented.
`package` (other than in package-info.java) and `import` declarations are not documented anyway, so Javadoc will not look at the comment in either way.

As it doesn't matter for Javadoc, you can as well use the "less heavy" `/* ... */` version.

Comment: +1 [Here's the documentation reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#comments) if you want to add it to your answer. Specifically the section **Placement of comments**, where it states: *"Documentation comments are recognized only when placed immediately before class, interface, constructor, method, or field declarations"*.  It also sort of identifies the discussion on this question: *"A common mistake is to put an `import` statement between the class comment and the class declaration. Avoid this, as the Javadoc tool will ignore the class comment."*

Answer (score 6):

If you use `/** */` documenting tools will grab it so you're better off using it :)

Comment: Is that always the Right Thing, though? What if the copyright only applies to the code? What if the Javadoc API is licensed/copyrighted differently?

Comment: This is actually incorrect for the example code given in the question. See [Paŭlo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323983/29995) and my comment on it.

Comment: Javadoc will not grab stuff before an import statement like in the example in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I just read some open source java projects, found they all use `/* */`